# How can I prevent code execution in one page

Tags: javascript

I have to websites **index.html** and **index.php** and both pages contain a javascript file **script.js**.

I'd like to execute some code from **script.js** to **index.html** and other to **index.php**.

Is it possible to do this?

**JS Code**

```
function ChangeColor()
{
   button.addEventListener("mouseover", () =>
   {
     button.classList.remove("red");
     button.classList.add("blue");
   }
  )
  button.addEventListener("mouseout", () =>
  {
    button.classList.add("blue");
    button.classList.remove("red");
  }
  )
}

function CheckErrors()
{
  //Content
}
```

In My previous code, I want execute function **ChangeColor** in both websites because I have a button, hovewer my second function I want execute it just in **index.html** because I have a form.

How can I do this?, maybe with window object??

Comment: Why not split the scripts into different files?

Comment: I thought it, but I'd like if I can avoid repeat some lines in two diferents files

Comment: You don’t need to repeat anything. You can split the script into three files: one for common functionality, one specifically for `index.html`, one specifically for `index.php`. Then load two script files for each page appropriately.

Comment: Ok I see it's the best way for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `location.pathname` is equal to `/index.html`:

```js
function ChangeColor() {
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        button.classList.remove("red");
        button.classList.add("blue");
    })
    button.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        button.classList.add("blue");
        button.classList.remove("red");
    })
}

if (location.pathname == "/index.html") {
    function CheckErrors() {
        //Content
    }
    CheckErrors();
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.  I don't know why

Comment: @javi-ur96 Updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: Hi @Spectric, It doesn't

Comment: Can you visit `index.html` and check what `location.pathname` returns?

Comment: It returns /index.html and If I do in index.php /index.php.   I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @javi-ur96 Is this your whole script? If yes: `ChangeColor` is never called, `button` is undefined, and `CheckErrors` is empty.

Comment: It doesn't, it's an example

Comment: @javi-ur96 Did you call the functions?